# How to do distance calculation and clustering for event sequences in TraMineR?

Tags: r, traminer

I've been using TraMineR for a while now, even though I consider myself a begginer user. The same goes for R language.

Yet, I've been able to successfully perform a few optimal matching analysis. Now I'm trying to do the same for event sequences, but I actually can't find the functions for it, neither in the documentation nor in the user guide.

Is there any `seqedist` function or something of the sort ? (as opposed to `seqdist`, but taking an event sequence as an input) I appreciate the help, thanks !

I tried to comment on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94247/how-to-measure-multichannel-distances-between-event-sequences/94347#94347) question, but unfortunately i don't have enough reputation. But I'm not being able to find any `seqedist` function, nor in the help function withoit R enviroment nor in the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `seqedist` function in `TraMineRextras`. In addition to the online help page of the function, you may find some explanation and illustration in the following paper (preprint available on [http//traminer.unige.ch](http://traminer.unige.ch/) )

Ritschard, G., Bürgin, R. & Studer, M. (2013), "Exploratory Mining of Life Event Histories", In McArdle, J.J. & Ritschard, G. (eds) Contemporary Issues in Exploratory Data Mining in the Behavioral Sciences. Series: Quantitative Methodology, pp. 221-253. New York: Routledge.